# XML to DataTable (list item)

Tags: c#, xml, datatables

Here is my schema of xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfResultstring xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Resultstring>
    <Key>Blablabla : </Key>
    <Values>
      <string>79,0441326460292</string>
      <string>76,0959542079328</string>
      <string>74,3061819154758</string>
      <string>78,687039788779</string>
    </Values>
    <Type>list</Type>
  </Resultstring>

  <Resultstring>
    <Key>Blablabla : </Key>
    <Values>
        <string>87,7110395931923</string>
    </Values>
    <Type>double</Type>
  </Resultstring>
</ArrayOfResultstring>
```

I need read this XML file and fill the datatable.

I'm trying with DataSet.

```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   ds.ReadXml(path);
   DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

And my output datatable is like.
[image: ss]

I need to show my items on table. Is there any way to read properly ?

Comment: This Xml is not valid. did you cut part of it ? May you [Edit] your question with your real Xml and bogus data but with the real begining and end ..

Comment: What is your SQL schema? do you want to store it in a single column or multiple?

Comment: @DipteeH I just need to show it on my page firstly.

Comment: @DragandDrop I edited my post. Can you please check it ?

Comment: Ok the Xml is valid, May I Ask for one more things : what is the display you want? Do we flattern Key and value or we repeat key for each value

Comment: @DragandDrop Actually it is not really matter. I think write line by line to height extended row for more than one value is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following xml linq which creates a separate row for each string :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication51
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("KEY", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("RESULTING_ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TYPE", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            foreach (XElement resultingString in doc.Descendants(ns + "Resultstring"))
            {
               string key = (string)resultingString.Element("Key");
               string type = (string)resultingString.Element("Type");
               string ids = string.Join(";", resultingString.Descendants("string").Select(x => (string)x));
               dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { key, ids, type });


            }

        }
    }

}
```

---

Code to put each string in a separate column

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication51
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            int maxString = doc.Descendants(ns + "Resultstring").Select(x => x.Descendants("string").Count()).Max();


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("KEY", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TYPE", typeof(string));
            for (int i = 0; i < maxString; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("RESULTING_ID_" + (i + 1).ToString(), typeof(string));
            }


            foreach (XElement resultingString in doc.Descendants(ns + "Resultstring"))
            {
                string key = (string)resultingString.Element("Key");
                string type = (string)resultingString.Element("Type");
                List<string> row =  resultingString.Descendants("string").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();
                row.Insert(0, key);
                row.Insert(1, type);
                dt.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can we merge the lines in datatable. Like one line which has a key and three value ?

Comment: I updates code and put a semicolon between the strings.

Comment: You mean column.  I updated code to put each string in a separate column.  If you want new row in same cell replace the semicolon with "\n".

Answer (score 1):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library, you can easily convert Xml file to DataTable with few lines of code.

For your sample xml file, you can extract the data into datatable as below

```
using (var p = new ChoXmlReader(** YOUR XML FILE **)
    .WithField("Key")
    .WithField("Value", xPath: "/Values/string")
    )
{
    var dt = p.SelectMany(r => ((Array)r.Value).OfType<string>().Select(r1 => new { Key = r.Key, Value = r1})).AsDataTable();
}
```

Output:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

your `Resultstring` `xml` node is repeating. Below code is working for me

```
<Resultstring>
    <Key>Blablabla : </Key>
    <Values>
      <string>79,0441326460292</string>
      <string>76,0959542079328</string>
      <string>74,3061819154758</string>
      <string>78,687039788779</string>
    </Values>
    <Type>list</Type>

    <Key>Blablabla : </Key>
    <Values>
        <string>87,7110395931923</string>
    </Values>
    <Type>double</Type>
  </Resultstring>
```

Dataset code

```
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   ds.ReadXml(path);
   DataTable dtKey = ds.Tables[0];
   DataTable dtValues = ds.Tables[1];
   DataTable dtstring = ds.Tables[2];
   DataTable dtType = ds.Tables[3];
```

Comment: have you paste shared xml?